# Relocate JSF-generated javascript

Tags: jsf

I am using lots of commandLinks in my app. For them to work, JSF generates some wild Javascript ( `function dpf(f) {var adp...` ). Sadly, the script-tag destroys my layout. (It really does - I am sure about that).

Is there a way to force JSF to generate the script-tag somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try to externalize your Javascript.
Instead of putting the Javascript code within your page, it will only include a script tag that points to a Javascript file.
To do that, modify your web.xml file to have that:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.externalizeJavaScript</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Not an option for my situation but it should work and I will therefore accept it.